# FInd and removed nested elements from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash

I have a json below like this

```
[
  {
    "monthlyData": [
      {
        "dateYear": "2020-07",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "45bf4792-c5a5-44ed-b7e8-57557c4f30ee",
            "date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "transactionId": "160",
            "amount": 70,
            "active": 1,
            "createdAt": "2020-07-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "version": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "hashId": "4"
  },
  {
    "monthlyData": [
      {
        "dateYear": "2020-08",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "38fe3c68-e6aa-4c57-b4d7-dc6c4f597269",
            "date": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "transactionId": "146",
            "active": 1,
            "createdAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "version": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "hashId": "5"
  }
]
```

I have an array with list of month-year as

```
let datesArr = ['2020-08','2020-09','2020-10','2020-11','2020-07']
```

Now I want to pick a date from `datesArr` one by one and find if the date matches with `dateYear` column in whole JSON array. A copy of JSON array should be created for those dates are matched. I want to keep only those object whose dates are getting matched.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do it efficiently with Javascript's forEach

The code below extracts the information you require.

```js
const bigTable = [{
    "monthlyData": [{
      "dateYear": "2020-07",
      "data": [{
        "id": "45bf4792-c5a5-44ed-b7e8-57557c4f30ee",
        "date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "transactionId": "160",
        "amount": 70,
        "active": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-07-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "version": 1
      }]
    }],
    "hashId": "4"
  },
  {
    "monthlyData": [{
      "dateYear": "2020-08",
      "data": [{
        "id": "38fe3c68-e6aa-4c57-b4d7-dc6c4f597269",
        "date": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "transactionId": "146",
        "active": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "version": 1
      }]
    }],
    "hashId": "5"
  }
]

const datesArr = ['2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-07']


console.log("Version 1: a separate object for each dateYear")
datesArr.forEach(dateYear => {
  console.log(dateYear+":-------------------");
  bigTable.forEach(monthlyArray => {
    monthlyArray.monthlyData.forEach(monthData => {
      if (dateYear === monthData.dateYear) {
        console.log(monthData)
      }
    })
  })
})


console.log("Version 2: a single array with an element for each element of datesArr")
const output = datesArr.map(dateYear => bigTable.filter(monthlyObject => 
    monthlyObject.monthlyData[0].dateYear=== dateYear
  )
)
console.log(output)
```

Depending on exactly how you want it to compile the result, which is not unambiguous from your question, you should be able to adjust it to your needs.

Without an example of the output that you want, all we can do is guess what you mean.

Comment: I need to add those dates into monthData who has not matched with datesArray with data as empty. what should i do >

Comment: Hmmmm... I think you are having difficulty conveying what exactly you want. Neither your question, nor your clarification here nor your clarifications to the other answerer, leave me any the wiser.

It would be far better if you could show *an example answer* of your desired output. Otherwise people are going to get frustrated trying to guess your meaning...

Comment: For example, in your question, you refer to the "dateYear column in the whole JSON array". The JSON array does not have a dateYear column: the dateYear property belongs to an element of an array that itself an element of the main JSON array.

Comment: Secondly, "A copy of JSON array should be created for those dates are matched. I want to keep only those object whose dates are getting matched." This is highly ambiguous to me. Do you want a SINGLE copy of the JSON array, covering all dateYears that are matched? Or one copy of the JSON array for each different dateYear?

Comment: Third, please be specific when you say "date" and "dateYear". You are asking us to select objects whose "dates" are matched, but we have to realise that you don't mean the "date" field, but the "dateYear" field.

Comment: Finally, the problem is made unnecessarily complex by having lots of unrelated fields thrown into the example. Ger rid of the ones that aren't essential to express the problem. Perhaps just keep one irrelevant field, such as "id", so that we know that there may be others, and therefore build a solution that is flexible, but not so many as to burden the questions with many lines of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array.filter**

```
let originalArray = [
    {
        "monthlyData": [
            {
                "dateYear": "2020-07",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "45bf4792-c5a5-44ed-b7e8-57557c4f30ee",
                        "date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "transactionId": "160",
                        "amount": 70,
                        "active": 1,
                        "createdAt": "2020-07-14T02:55:43.988Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
                        "version": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "hashId": "4"
    },
    {
        "monthlyData": [
            {
                "dateYear": "2020-08",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "38fe3c68-e6aa-4c57-b4d7-dc6c4f597269",
                        "date": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "transactionId": "146",
                        "active": 1,
                        "createdAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
                        "version": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "hashId": "5"
    }
];

let datesArr = ['2020-08','2020-09','2020-10','2020-11'];

let filtered = originalArray.filter(value => {
    value.monthlyData = value.monthlyData.filter(md => {
        return datesArr.includes(md.dateYear);
    })
    return value.monthlyData.length > 0;
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered))
```

This example will print this below (if that is what you want):

```
[
  {
    "monthlyData": [
      {
        "dateYear": "2020-08",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "38fe3c68-e6aa-4c57-b4d7-dc6c4f597269",
            "date": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "transactionId": "146",
            "active": 1,
            "createdAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "version": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "hashId": "5"
  }
]
```

**Edit for date object comparison**

if datesArr is like

```
let datesArr = [new Date('2020-08'),new Date('2020-09')];
```

You can use **array.some** inside second filter

```
let filtered = originalArray.filter(value => {
    value.monthlyData = value.monthlyData.filter(md => {
        return datesArr.some(value1 => value1.getTime() === new Date(md.dateYear).getTime());
    })
    return value.monthlyData.length > 0;
})
```

And of course if original array has also Date object, you can discard
`new Date(md.dateYear).getTime()` use `md.dateYear.getTime()` instead

**Edit for your comment**:

> I need to add those dates into monthData who has not matched with
> datesArray with data as empty. what should i do.

You can use below code for that

```
let newArr = []
datesArr.forEach(date => {
    let element = originalArray.find(value => {
        value.monthlyData = value.monthlyData.filter(md => {
            return date === md.dateYear;
        })
        return value.monthlyData.length > 0;
    })

    if (!element){
        element = {
            "monthlyData": [
                {
                    "dateYear": date,
                    "data": []
                }
            ],
            "hashId": "something?"
        }
    }else {
        // make a clone
        element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element))
    }
    newArr.push(element);
})
```

Comment: Instead if using includes of datestr. what needs to change if i want to compare date using date object

Comment: I edited my answer according to that look at edit section

Comment: I need to add those dates into monthData who has not matched with datesArray with data as empty. what should i do. Please help

Comment: It is not clear what you said, give an example please. You want to keep dates in original array with an empty data? or You want to add dates which are in datesArr and not in original array?

Comment: Current logic is fine but dates those are in datesArr but not in original arr should be added on key "dateYear" in original array and data should be empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219808/discussion-between-techchain-and-ahmetsarias).